# Reduce false positive in HOG

Tags: opencv, svm, object-detection

I have implemented car detector using HOG and it is working quite okay at the moment. Unfortunately I have a lot of false positive for the classifier. 
**What I have done so far** 
I had changed the ratio (positive:negative) of samples from `1:1` to `1:3` and it lower the false positive to some extend. Can some one help to reduce the false positive for the classifier.
**My approach to implement HOG** 
 
Get the HOG features (blocks only) for the complete image.
Extract the positive features based on the label information and window size.
Extract the negative samples by randomly drawing the rectangle and checking for collision with the object in which I am interested.
Train the linear svm.
Testing the classifier.

Comment: use random subsets of huge labeled databases for training, then auto-test your classifier on the rest of the database. repeat until you've found the best training set or add new samples to database.

Comment: I have 1000 positive samples and 3000 negative samples at the moment. I don't understand your comment. Can you please rephrase.  @Micka

Comment: Google for _cross validation_

Comment: I think this page could help you: http://www.geocities.ws/talh_davidc/

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it is not the perfect solution but I hope it helps you.

I was using HOG descriptor + SMV classifier for specific object detection. In order to reduce the false positive results, despite the fact that is important to adjust the number of false and true training samples, at the end I had to adjust empirically the GAMMA and Cost parameters of Radial Basis Function (RBF) kernel SVM. Probably if you increased your GAMMA value , you will have less false positive results, but maybe there'll be some miss detections.

[image]

*The effect of the inverse-width parameter of the Gaussian kernel (γ) for a fixed value of the soft-margin constant. For small values of γ (upper left) the decision boundary is nearly linear. As γ increases the flexibility of the decision boundary increases. Large values of γ lead to
overfitting (bottom).*

I leave you some links as reference:

[A User’s Guide to Support Vector Machines](http://pyml.sourceforge.net/doc/howto.pdf)

[Using SVMs for Scientists and Engineers](http://covartech.github.io/blog/2013/07/24/using-svms/)

Regards.